# Laravel 5.1, moving folders

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

I've got a simple Laravel app that I've just been told that the public DIR has to be in quite a different place to the core code.

I need to have s'thing like this:

```
folder-root
 | - site
 | - | - someFolder
 | - | - | - codeFolder
 | - | - | - | - app
 | - | - | - | - bootstrap
 | - | - | - | - config (etc etc etc)
 | - newPublicFolder
 | - | - index.php
```

I've copied all my files to this structure locally and altered my public index.php file to point to the bootstrap/autoload.php file and can echo out test variables from that file, so I know it is pointing it to it correctly.

Is there a guide anywhere to do this, or is there a config file I'm missing?

UPDATE: This is from my apache error log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function make() on a non-object in /var/www/test/site/public/index.php on line 49
```

UPDATE 2:

I've ONLY copied the files over. The DB remains the same and I've not run any compser updates or anything.. if that makes a differnce?

Cheers!

Comment: Are you actually having issues, or are you just asking if you've done it the right way?

Comment: I'm having issues... I've only changed the index.php file in the public folder to point correctly to the bootstrap file.. and the site is not working. I was wondering if there are other config settings that are less obvious (to me) that I need to update.

Comment: Did you remember to update both lines 22 and 36 in `public/index.php`? From your error, it looks like line 36 is not returning a real version of the Laravel application instance.

Comment: Yes i'd done that, they're both the same path.

Comment: And you've done `composer install` or copied your `vendor` folder, right? That is to say, `bootstrap/autoload.php` line 17 is finding something, right? I guess it would be, otherwise your error wouldn't be about calling `->make()` on a non-object, but not being able to find the file/class.

Comment: I 'only' copied the code, including the vendor folder (I copied everything).

I just echoed a string on vendor/autoload.php and it came through fine, suggesting that yes, the paths are correct.

Comment: Did you change `$app = require_once('PATH_TO_BOOTSTRAP_APP')`?

Comment: If you change that, it must work properly

Comment: @AdityaGiri if you mean line 36 as alexrussel asked, then yes. However, my line was: $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';   I simply changed that path to the new bootstrap and as I've said, it does appear to be the right path as I can output vars form it.. and if I change that path to giberish, it stops echoing those vars

Comment: Actually I am saying about both line 22 and line 36

Comment: I just went full retard... I'd copied autoload twice... changed the $app to point to app.php.. working (with errors, but it's seeing results..) cheers!!! and D'oh!

Comment: That line itself isn't the problem - it's because `$app` is not correctly initialised, which happens in `bootstrap/app.php:14`, but based on setting up the autoloader in `bootstrap/autoload.php:17`. Maybe stick a `var_dump($app);` after line 14 in `bootstrap/app.php` and see if it's `null` or actually something.

Comment: Yeah Try what is said by @alexrussell

Answer (score 0):

To all in the same boat and here because of a Google search..

I'd copied line 22 and pasted into line 36.

I'd missed that the first was to 'autoload.php' and the second was to 'app,php'

Rookie mistake, but if it helps you.. all good..

Comment: Haha, d'oh! Glad you got it sorted.